# Escape @ character in git proxy password

Tags: git, msysgit

I have git proxy config as 'http.proxy=http://userId:**pwd@123**@ipaddress:port' but while cloning a remote project, I'm getting error as

```
Cloning into git...
error: Couldn't resolve proxy '123@ipaddress' while accessing http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

How to escape the '@' character in password?

Pls note: I cannot change the password.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

I'd try using the URL Encoded value of the @ symbol (`%40`) if you're passing the password in the proxy url:

```
http.proxy=http://userId:pwd%40123@ipaddress:port
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this same trick but with 'git clone http://user:pwd%40123@ip:port' and it doesn't work. So I guess git doesn't use curl in this situation?

Comment: interesting... not sure.  It's probably worth trying to see what actually gets sent across the wire in this case.

Comment: This helped me. You should separately url-encode both name and password parts. This will help you avoid any problems with special chars. For example there can be ":" sign which will also lead to problems.

Comment: This is also awesome for when you have '@' in the username e.g. when you have email addresses as usernames.

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my problem after two days' struggle...really hard to find the reason for this kind of problem.

Comment: Hello. Is there a list of URL Encoded values so i can save it and consult when i need it ?

Answer (score 80):

Note (November 2013)

Encoding the url (especially any special character in a password) is the right solution.
The `.netrc` mentioned below is only for remote repo url, not for the proxy used to resolve said remote repo url.

For said encoding, see "[Percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)":

> Percent-encoding, also known as URL [encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding), is a mechanism for encoding information in a [Uniform Resource Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) (URI) under certain circumstances. Although it is known as URL encoding it is, in fact, used more generally within the main [Uniform Resource Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) (URI) set, which includes both [Uniform Resource Locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) (URL) and [Uniform Resource Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name) (URN). As such, it is also used in the preparation of data of the application/x-www-form-urlencoded [media type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type), as is often used in the submission of [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) [form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_%28web%29) data in [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) requests.
>
> Reserved characters after percent-encoding:

```
!   #   $    &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   /   :   ;   =   ?   @   [   ]
%21 %23 %24 %26 %27 %28 %29 %2A %2B %2C %2F %3A %3B %3D %3F %40 %5B %5D
```

---

Original answer (May 2011)

Two comments:

- having a password for a server accessed with http (not https) is... strange. The password isn't encrypted during communications between client and server;
- you could setup a `.netrc` (or `_netrc` for Windows) in your `$HOME`, with the following content

```
    machine ipaddress:port
    login userId
    password pwd@
```

The curl used by Git bbehind the scene would handle the encoding just fine, `@` or no `@`.

Comment: Thanks for ur answers. The server was network drive where only myself and other 2 developers will be using. So I think there is no need for encryption. And I will try using netrc sometime.

Comment: @Karthik: that will allow you to simply use: `http://123@ipaddress:port/...` as a cloning address, without having to add user and password information.

Answer (score 13):

You have to [percent-encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) | [encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the special characters. E.g. instead of this:

```
http://user:Pa@s@http-gateway.domain.org:80
```

you write this:

```
http://user:Pa%40s@http-gateway.domain.org:80
```

So `@` gets replaced with `%40`.

Answer (score 12):

URL encode any unusual characters.

[List of url codes.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

```
@ character is %40
```

In my git config file, I have encoded 'just' the user name for instance:

```html
https://myemail%40gmail.com@myrepo.org/api.git
```

Answer (score 8):

For example, your password stored in environment variable `GIT_PASSWORD`, username - `GIT_USERNAME`, then:

```
git clone http://${GIT_USERNAME}:$(echo -n $GIT_PASSWORD | hexdump -v -e '"x" 1/1 "%02X"' | tr x %)@repository.git
```

Explanation of: `echo -n $GIT_PASSWORD | hexdump -v -e '"x" 1/1 "%02X"' | tr x %`

1. Print password: `$GIT_PASSWORD` <- `hello`
2. Convert 'hello' to hex: `hello` <- `x68x65x6Cx6Cx6F`
3. Change each 'x' to '%': `x68x65x6Cx6Cx6F` <- `%68%65%6C%6C%6F`

Comment: In the first point of the explanation did you mean to use $GIT_**PASSWORD** instead of $GIT_REPOSITORY ?

Comment: @NinjuBohra, thanks!