# Git clone with password @

Tags: git, shell, github, command-line, escaping

I need to escape the @ that use the password because it is confused with the host.

Example 1:
`git clone https://user:p@ssword@github.com/user/repo.git`

When I run the above example, it's wrong, because as the password has @ he understands that the next parameter is the host. tried to escape with \ or you can use the url between "" but it was not.

Example 2:
`(echo user; echo p@ssword) | git clone https://github.com/usuario/repo.git`

When I use only the command,`git clone https://github.com/usuario/repo.git` he asks the User and Password, so I used the above command, which is the same that I use to change the root password on a line only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think what you are looking is to escape the special character @, which you can use encode %40 instead of @. This link might help [Escape @ character in git proxy password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password)

Answer (score 5):

You can replace **@** with its URL encoded format **%40**

if your password is **password@99**. Change it to **password%4099**

```
git clone https://username:password%4099@bitbucket.org/sarat.git
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the link [Git Configure](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/#password-caching)

Configure your git account in local -

`git config --global user.name myName`

`git config --global user.email myEmail`

The following command will save your password in memory for sometime.

`$ git config --global credential.helper cache`

## Set git to use the credential memory cache

`$ git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'`

## Set the cache to timeout after 1 hour (setting is in seconds)

Hope this would help you

Comment: This does not indicate how to escape the character.