# Git: clone from HTTP repository when username contains "@" sign

Tags: git

I'm trying to clone from some git repository, with a command like:

```
git clone username@path.to.server/repository
```

The problem is that my `username` contains the `@` char within.

When I try to clone using some dummy user name without the `@` char, I get authentication error. But, once I try with my username, I get:

```
> git clone myuser@mydomain.com@path.to.server/repository
fatal: unable to access .... Could not resolve host mydomain.com@path.to.server
```

I tried escaping the `@` sign using backslash, and using 2,3,4 and 5 backslashes - still the same problem..

Any ideas how to overcome it?

---

**Solution:**

Thanks to those who answered/commented with references to other threads.

The very simple solution, detailed in the references, is to use `%40`, which is the ASCII encoding of the char `@`. Tried it - it works!

```
git clone myuser%40mydomain.com@path.to.server/repository
```

Comment: Basically the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161081/git-clone-with-password

Comment: Also very similar, with same solution: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10050877/151344

Comment: PLEASE don't post the solution as part of your question, post it as new answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

why not try to clone the git
`git clone pathTORepor` and then git will prompt you to type username then type your `username` and `password` if needed