# How to handle @ in pip install with git?

Tags: python, git, pip

I need to install a package using pip via Git.

The password of the repo contains `@`.

According to [Git clone with password @](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161081/git-clone-with-password), I tried the following:

```
pip install git+http://user:xxxx%40xxxx@url...
```

Which threw:

> fatal: Authentication failed for

Same with:

```
   pip install git+http://user:xxxx@xxxx@url...
   pip install git+http://user:'xxxx@xxxx'@url...
```

How can I install a package using pip via git+http giving the credentials directly to command line when the password contains `@` in `sh` ?

---

Edit:

To make it clear: I am **NOT** using Github but TFS17 and I have **NO OTHER CHOICE** but provide username and password inside the URL.

Comment: `pip install git+https://<PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN>@github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPOSITORY>.git`  source: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Comment: That reminds me of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51245733/6309... which also had no answer.

Comment: Can you locally clone the repo and then pip install using the files directly ?

Comment: @pLOPeGG I could, but I am still facing the same issue with the `@` character.

Comment: just throwing it out there, maybe `export PASS="123@456" && pip install git+http://user:$PASS@url...` will work? pip uses your shell for git so maybe using env vars will fix all the escaping issues

Comment: @Ron Quoting helps when the string needs to be protected from the shell, but the error message here does not come from the shell, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @RonSerruya Unfortunately the password is already in an env variable :(

Comment: @FlorianCastelain you mean that you can't even clone the repo with a git command ? Then this is not only a pip problem but TFS17 I guess.

Comment: Definitely take `pip` itself out of the equation first: get to the point where you can run `git clone` successfully even in some fully automated setup. Then re-introduce pip and figure out how to make sure pip invokes git with the method that works when fully automated.