# Issue when configure GIT behind a proxy

Tags: git, proxy

I'm executing `git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@proxy.example:3128` to configure a proxy in GIT. The problem is when my user contains an `@`.

**User:** myuser@test

**Password:** 1234

If I run: `git config --global http.proxy http://myuser@test:1234@proxy.example:3128`

I get the error: `Couldn't resolve proxy 'test'`

How can I solve it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the encoded value of `@` : `%40123`

Like this :

```
git config --global http.proxy http://myuser%40123test:1234@proxy.example:3128
```

source : [Escape @ character in git proxy password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password)