# How do i configure linux terminal to use proxy having a username and password with "@"?

Tags: linux, proxy, terminal, passwords

Am using a university network that uses a proxy, which has its login details in the format:

registration: number@students (e.g **"i39/3433/2014@students"**)

and a password: password@uyn (e.g **"uns@uyn"**)

I am wondering how i will export these login credentials so that a Linux Mint 17 terminal will be is able to  install, update, and download.

Comment: This question has many duplicates : http://askubuntu.com/questions/60217/apt-get-update-with-an-in-password-error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can try on console

```
export http_proxy="http://user:pass@proxy.foo.bar"
```

If you don't have user/pass you can export as

```
export http_proxy="http://proxy.foo.bar"
```

replace "proxy.foo.bar" to an IP if you need

(I post as answer because I can't post as comment)