# Why is Personal Access Token not working for Bitbucket REST API?

Tags: bitbucket, access-token, git-clone, bitbucket-api

**TL/DR: (Why) does a name/PAT combination created in the Bitbucket web UI not work with Bitbucket REST API (or repo cloning)?**

I've been reading [various](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58) [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/updating-build-status-for-commits/) on Bitbucket [REST](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/reference/rest-api/) [API](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/command-line-rest/) and [Personal Access Tokens](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/personal-access-tokens-939515499.html), with the intent of using the latter when invoking the former.

All that I have read so far have said -- in more elaborative words -- that this is possible.

Following along, I created a Personal Access Token (`PAT`) in the Bitbucket web UI.
Per the screenshot below (posted at the bottom, so as to not break up the text flow), the `PAT` Name is "test", and let's say the `PAT` value is `Rzg4MGUyN4m4N9U3O1HQHO3ABJyp7xClvsan7sAmFEPy`

**Why, when I try to use this `PAT`, do I get an "Authentication failed" error?** For example:

```
user@bld_svr:~$ curl -L -u test:Rzg4MGUyN4m4N9U3O1HQHO3ABJyp7xClvsan7sAmFEPy -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://bitbucket.svr.com/rest/build-status/1.0/commits/5764bb32f80813b3bbcbf6496c113c1830c52bb0 -d '{"state":"INPROGRESS","key":"job_434","url":"http://bld_svr:8080//blue/organizations/jenkins/prj/detail/prj/434/pipeline"}'
{"errors":[{"context":null,"message":"Authentication failed. Please check your credentials and try again.","exceptionName":"com.atlassian.bitbucket.auth.IncorrectPasswordAuthenticationException"}]}
```

My readings have led me to believe that all that's necessary is:

1. Creating the `PAT` in the Bitbucket UI
2. Using the Name/`PAT` combination the same as one would use username/password

---

Trying to debug the issue a little, [this page](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/updating-build-status-for-commits/), specifically, indicates that Name/PAT should be usable to `git clone` repos. But that also fails:

```
$ git clone https://bitbucket.svr.com/scm/key/a_project.git
Cloning into 'a_project'...
Username for 'https://bitbucket.svr.com': test
Password for 'https://test@bitbucket.svr.com': # I typed in "Rzg4MGUyN4m4N9U3O1HQHO3ABJyp7xClvsan7sAmFEPy" here
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.svr.com/scm/key/a_project.git/'
```

**Can anyone give me the straight dope on the Bitbucket `PAT`s and how they should be configured/used with Bitbucket REST API, and even just plain `git clone`ing?**

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the PAT Name is "`test`",

Actually, you would need to use your BitBucket user account name, not the PAT name, as username:

```
git clone https://username:<token>@bitbucketserver.com/scm/projectname/teamsinspace.git
```

You also have the syntax ([seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43114159/6309))

```
git clone "https://x-token-auth:{tokenHere}@bitbucket.org/yourRepoOwnerHere/RepoNameHere"
```

And you can use [`gildas/git-credential-bitbucket`](https://github.com/gildas/git-credential-bitbucket) as a way to cache your token and reuse it automatically

```sh
git credential-bitbucket store <<EOM
protocol=https
host=bitbucket.org
username=xxx
clientid=yyy
secret=zzz

git remote add bitbucket https://xxx@bitbucket.org/path/to/repo.git
git config credential.helper bitbucket
```