# Git checking out external project in jenkins pipeline using user and password

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38462645/1485926) the way of checking out an external project from a jenkins pipeline is as follows:

```
git branch: 'master',
    credentialsId: '12345-1234-4696-af25-123455',
    url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org:company/repo.git'
```

The author of the post also says:

> If you're using the ssh url then your credentials must be username + private key. If you're using the https clone url instead of the ssh one, then your credentials should be username + password.

However, not fully clear how the second case works (https URL and username + password)... Which syntax is use in this case for `creadentialsId`? Or that field is not used and others are used to specify username and password? Could somebody provide an example of it, please?

Thanks!

Comment: That answer is a bit outdated. Best practices are now this: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/. You will have more robust options for credentials with that.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Why using a general SCM Plugin if there's a special [Git plugin/step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/) that supports `credentialsId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the username and password on Jenkins by following:

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/

> Adding new global credentials To add new global credentials to your
> Jenkins instance:
>
> If required, ensure you are logged in to Jenkins (as a user with the
> Credentials > Create permission). From the Jenkins home page (i.e. the
> Dashboard of the Jenkins classic UI), click Manage Jenkins > Manage
> Credentials. image
>
> Under Stores scoped to Jenkins on the right, click on Jenkins. image
>
> Under System, click the Global credentials (unrestricted) link to
> access this default domain. image
>
> Click Add Credentials on the left. Note: If there are no credentials
> in this default domain, you could also click the add some credentials
> link (which is the same as clicking the Add Credentials link). From
> the Kind field, choose the type of credentials to add. From the Scope
> field, choose either: Global - if the credential/s to be added is/are
> for a Pipeline project/item. Choosing this option applies the scope of
> the credential/s to the Pipeline project/item "object" and all its
> descendent objects. System - if the credential/s to be added is/are
> for the Jenkins instance itself to interact with system administration
> functions, such as email authentication, agent connection, etc.
> Choosing this option applies the scope of the credential/s to a single
> object only. Add the credentials themselves into the appropriate
> fields for your chosen credential type: Secret text - copy the secret
> text and paste it into the Secret field. Username and password -
> specify the credential’s Username and Password in their respective
> fields. Secret file - click the Choose file button next to the File
> field to select the secret file to upload to Jenkins. SSH Username
> with private key - specify the credentials Username, Private Key and
> optional Passphrase into their respective fields. Note: Choosing Enter
> directly allows you to copy the private key’s text and paste it into
> the resulting Key text box. Certificate - specify the Certificate and
> optional Password. Choosing Upload PKCS#12 certificate allows you to
> upload the certificate as a file via the resulting Upload certificate
> button. Docker Host Certificate Authentication - copy and paste the
> appropriate details into the Client Key, Client Certificate and Server
> CA Certificate fields. In the ID field, specify a meaningful
> credential ID value - for example,
> jenkins-user-for-xyz-artifact-repository. The inbuilt (default)
> credentials provider can use upper- or lower-case letters for the
> credential ID, as well as any valid separator character, other
> credential providers may apply further restrictions on allowed
> characters or lengths. However, for the benefit of all users on your
> Jenkins instance, it is best to use a single and consistent convention
> for specifying credential IDs. Note: This field is optional. If you do
> not specify its value, Jenkins assigns a globally unique ID (GUID)
> value for the credential ID. Bear in mind that once a credential ID is
> set, it can no longer be changed. Specify an optional Description for
> the credential/s. Click OK to save the credentials

Then, use the ID from that in the credentialsId field in the code above.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! So you mean that is not possible to specify the username and password *directly* in the pipeline file and I need to put them in a jenkins credential, then use the jenkins credential. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @fgalan It is possible but it's unsafe to store pwds in SCM repos. Otherwise your understanding is correct. See [this answer for using the Credentials Binding Plugin/`withCredentials` in a `Jenkinsfile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68765193/1744774).