# SVN credentials from command line..?

Tags: wordpress, svn

I've never used SVN except to push updates to my WordPress plugins.  All of the plugins I've ever worked with are under the same account at WordPress.org.  I honestly don't remember how I setup SVN credentials the very first time I ever did one, but ever since then, I've never had to enter them again.  Any new plugin I create just works for me.

Now, though, I've got a new plugin that I created on a different WordPress.org account.  I was able to check out the new plugin repo from WordPress, but then when I try to check in my plugin files I get an authentication error.

I'm assuming this is because somewhere it has my primary account's credentials saved and that's what it's trying to use here, which won't work of course.  It's never asking me for credentials of any kind.

I tried to specify different credentials at the command line like this...

```
svn ci -m "Adds files for 1.0.0 release" --username myusername --password mypassword
```

The thing is, my password has some )'s in it, and when I try that command I get this error back:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

So at this point I'm stuck and I don't know what to do.  Any info on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I changed my password to something more basic, and now when I use the --username and --password options it works fine.  So I guess one thing that would help is to figure out how I can use passwords with special characters in them from the command line without getting a syntax error..??

Comment: Did you try to percent-encode your special character in that password? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6172831/6309)

Comment: so URL encoding the password value..??  That seems odd, but I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the --password option. Subversion asks you then for the password.

This is also saver as your password is not stored in cleartext in your history

Comment: I should have mentioned I tried that but it doesn't work for me.  For some reason if I just specify a user and not a password it gives me a message like "no authentication or too many tries."  It's not locked, though, I can still get to it on another machine.

Comment: @AndrewAngell: You should then delete your SVN saved passwords. they should be in your home directories svn-folder: either  (%APPDATA%\subversion or ~/.svn)

Comment: From what I read I would just delete the /auth folder in there, but when I do that I just get messages about "no credentials" and it doesn't prompt me to enter credentials.  That's why I'm so lost here.  The stuff I read isn't doing what it says it should do.  Maybe I should just completely remove SVN and re-install it..??