# How can I escape `@` of password in git URL

Tags: git, escaping

**Excuses:**
I see this: [Escape @ character in git proxy password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password)
But It's about `http.proxy` param, and `p%4055` does not work for me about `url` param.

**My question:**
I use git version 1.7.1
My password repository is: `p@55`
And I use `gitlab` server, and `centos` for client.
In `.git/config` file, i have be like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = http://user:p@55@domain.com:port/repo.git
```

But when I pull it, Gave me this error:

```
error: Couldn't resolve host '55:domain.com' while accessing ...
```

I know about escape `@` char, but:

I try `p\@55`, Gave me this error:

```
fatal: bad config file line 8 in .git/config
```

I try `p%4055`, Gave me this error:

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing ...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape @ character in git proxy password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password)

Comment: Use `http://user:p%4055@domain.com:port/repo.git`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I see, but that's for `http.proxy` params, and I try `%40` and does not work for `url` param.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As You can see end of my question about try `p%4055`, and does not work!

Comment: What version of Git are you using? (both locally  and on the remote server)

Comment: please use sshpass as I added in my below answer

Comment: And what about using SSH with an SSH key (without passphrase or by using `ssh-agent`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just upgrade git version from 1.7.1 to 2.11.1 and this worked for me:

```
url = http://user:p%4055@domain.com:port/repo.git
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the URL Encoded value of the @ - (%40) symbol.

an example in your case:

URL = http://user:p%4055@domain.com:port/repo.git

**Edit:**

if above method doesn't work please use below method:

sshpass -p password git clone ssh://username@onboard.com/srv/git/repo

Comment: As I said in end of my question about `p%4055`, give me error....
so, as I said, I want to git pull, and not clone! and so I don't want use it in CLI, and I want put in config file.

Comment: i added one more method sshpass

Comment: I want put into config file, and I don't want to use under CLI. and also I want to do git pull and not git clone!, and so http protocol not ssh....

Comment: `sshpass -p p@55 git pull` it worked. but as I said, I want to config git config file. one of the reason is the password show in history for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use git credentials helper:

> [Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-on-github)