# Git Clone: Illegal Port Number

Tags: bash, git, amazon-web-services, fatal-error, git-clone

I'm trying clone a repository with http using the username and password lik e this:

```
git clone https://username:password@gitlab.com/user/repo.git
```

However I get this error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://username:password@gitlab.com/user/repo.git': Illegal port number
```

I'm trying to do this on a EC2 Instance that is using AWS Linux.
I can get this working if I do it manually, and use only the username in the clone and then put the password to the prompt, but I'm trying to clone the repository with a bash script.

Comment: Please specify whether you can reproduce this with the exact URL given (including the username `username` and the password `password`, f/e). If it can only be reproduced with a username and password that have certain characteristics, then the example given here need to have those characteristics; most particularly, the content of the literal password is relevant.

Comment: Alternately, I'd suggest running `bash -x yourscript`, and presenting the exact line for the `git clone` invocation -- if there are hidden, nonprintable, or otherwise surprising values in the variables you're suggesting, `xtrace` logs (with a new enough bash) should display them.

Comment: (I suspect strongly that this is a duplicate of [How can I escape `@` of password in git URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44733982/how-can-i-escape-of-password-in-git-url), but the question isn't detailed enough to permit certainty on that count).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your comments. I did research, but the thing really is that I might not know what to research about, because that was all that I got from the error. I posted this question honestly only after 4 hours of trying to find some answers to the problems beforehand. 

The password contains characters such as # and % so that might cause some weird behavior there? I'll proceed to test this out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm curious to hear the results of those tests -- please do [edit] the question based on what you find. If you need to know how to make a password with a literal `%` work, for example, that's a lot more concrete; just be sure that whatever placeholder or example password you include generates the same problem.

Comment: Placeholder validity should be easy to test, since this error happens before the remote server has been contacted, much less had a chance whether to test whether a given credential pair is correct -- so if a dummy password generates an authentication error instead of an "illegal port number", we know the issue at hand is resolved. Best of luck!

Answer (score 4):

With Charles' comments I figured out the reason why this error occurred. The password contained a %-character and a 4-character, which is the URL Encoded value of @-character. This caused it treat it as a proxy password (if I understood correctly.. basically the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password).)

So what I did was I changed the password, and now it works just fine!