# 407 Authentication required npm

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy, configuration, npm-install

Hello everyone I´ve been trying to configure and use npm on my enterprise PC without success.

I´ve set proxy, https-proxy, strict-ssl false, registry http://registry.npmjs.org
proxy has been set like this "http://user:password@proxy_ip:proxy:port"
Where the password has a special character written in urlencode.

```
npm config get proxy
```

returns proxy with credentials as they should be.

I have cleared my npm cache and tried again.

No success.

Any ideas what can be the problem?

Comment: Go to `C:\Users\Your User\AppData\Roaming` and delete the `npm` folder, then do the following command:`npm cache clear --force` and `npm cache verify` 
and then execute this command: `npm i -g npm@latest --verbose`.

Comment: @SuhasGavad Same result, im going to try now setting domain in the proxy url

Comment: Must likely you will have to do your proxy settings again. As it will be lost be re-installing npm.

Comment: Doesn't work with NTLM Proxy.

Comment: Proxy password - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54546625/410439

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Usually, when you are behind a corporate proxy, it is needed to add the domain where you are at. Given that also the characters should be URL encoded, it would look like:

https://domain%5Cusername:password@proxy:port

Comment: what is mean by domain here? can u clarify.

Comment: I think he means Active Directory Domain

Comment: use encodeURIComponent to generate encoded password. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent  and output of encodeURIComponent stuff into http://username:encodedpass@proxy.com

Answer (score 19):

I recommend reading through this article to configure the proxy for npm. 
http://wil.boayue.com/blog/2013/06/14/using-npm-behind-a-proxy/

- `npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:proxyport`
- `npm config set http-proxy http://proxy.company.com:proxyport`
- `npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:proxyport`

Hope this is useful for you!

Comment: Thank you Suhas i have already found the solution as lautit said the domain was left in my proxy configuration.
I have read quite a lot before asking but couldn´t fix the problem

Comment: use encodeURIComponent to generate encoded password. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent  and output of encodeURIComponent stuff into http://username:encodedpass@proxy.com

Comment: Using npm 9.7.2: "http-proxy is not a valid npm option" The other two options work as expected.

Answer (score 16):

We should add proxy with username and password to avoid this error.
For example:

- username: admin
- password: admin123
- proxy: 172.10.3.21
- port: 3128

---

```
npm config set proxy http://admin:admin123@172.10.3.21:3128
npm config set https-proxy http://admin:admin123@172.10.3.21:3128
```

Comment: Is there no way to do this than to expose password like this? I was hoping on Windows machine 'Credential manager' would work, but it does not!

Answer (score 9):

Editing the .npmrc file in user folder worked for me.
I set the proxy and npm registry as follows:

```
proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port/
https-proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Note : for usenames and passwords containing special charcters, the characters need to be encoded in the proxy configuration. 
e.g if username is "user" and password is "1234@user", then the .npmrc file will look like :

```
proxy=http://user:1234%40user@proxy:port/
https-proxy=http://user:1234@user@proxy:port
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

where, %40 is the encoded form of "@".
In my case, the pound symbol(#) was not getting accepted in username or password(Dont know why).

Answer (score 1):

if you use windows and cntlm and you get a 407 error from cntlm proxy server, make sure that your PassNTLMv2 in the cntlm.ini is up-to-date, as you have to recreate it, everytime that you change domain password.

Answer (score 1):

As others mention above you should set both the proxy and https-proxy configuration variables. as below:

```
https-proxy=http://userName:password@urlOfYourProxy:8080/
```

What no mentions is that the https-proxy variable should point to a proxy url that uses the http protocol NOT the https protocol (as shown above)!! Pretty darned counter intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error on my corporate machine and this command in Terminal fixed it:

```
proxyOn () {
    export PROXY_CREDS=http://localhost:9000
    export ALL_PROXY=${PROXY_CREDS}
    export https_proxy=${PROXY_CREDS}
    export http_proxy=${PROXY_CREDS}
    export HTTP_PROXY=${PROXY_CREDS}
    export HTTPS_PROXY=${PROXY_CREDS}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The character dot . , dont work on http request but &#46 remplace it

1. Before
   npm config set proxy http://name.surname:pwrd@host:port
2. After
   npm config set proxy http://name&#46surname:pwrd@host:port

Answer (score 0):

When I received that error it was because our security team changed the url of the proxy. Updating to the new url fixed it for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34472356)