# Unable to download npm packages. 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: angular, fiddler, ntlm, http-proxy

I'm having difficulty to by pass proxy when trying to install npm packages on windows 10 machine in an angular app and getting the following error.

`407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. )`

I have tried possibly all the solutions I have found online. My `.npmrc` file has entries now like this

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
proxy=http://mydomainusername:password@proxy-domain:port
http-proxy=http://mydomainusername:password@proxy-domain:port
https-proxy=http://mydomainusername:password@proxy-domain:port
strict-ssl=false
```

I have tried various combinations (e.g. used IP addresses instead of domains, specified just the proxy-domain address without username and password) using npm config commands but not having any luck and keep getting the same error.

One thing that works is when I use Fiddler as a proxy as described in this [article](https://www.sharepointconfig.com/2017/04/using-npm-behind-a-proxy-that-uses-ntlm-authentication/) but I want to avoid fiddler adding athentication headers. Any ideas what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [407 Authentication required npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49902035/407-authentication-required-npm)

Comment: @AkashShrivastava I have also tried url encoding but that does not make a difference