# Ng Update causes 407 authenticationrequired

Tags: angular

I tried to update my angular-lib (ng update). Unfortunately it failed due to the following issue:

> The installed local Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable version. 
> Installing a temporary version to perform the update. 
> Installing packages for tooling via npm. 
> Installed packages for tooling via npm. 
> Using package manager: 'npm' 
> Collecting installed dependencies... 
> Found 33 dependencies. 
> Locating potential npmrc files: 
> Trying 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\etc\npmrc'...not found.
> Trying 'C:\Users\user.npmrc'...found.
> Trying 'C:\TFS.npmrc'...not found.
> Trying 'C:\TFS\Core.npmrc'...not found.
> Trying 'C:\TFS\Core\Development.npmrc'...not found.
> Trying 'C:\TFS\Core\Development\Source.npmrc'...not found.
> Trying 'C:\TFS\Core\Development\Source\Client.npmrc'...not found.
> Trying 'C:\TFS\Core\Development\Source\Client\ORG.npmrc'...not found.
> Trying 'C:\TFS\Core\Development\Source\Client\ORG\projects.npmrc'...not found.
> Trying 'C:\TFS\Core\Development\Source\Client\ORG\projects\org.npmrc'...not found.
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fplatform-browser
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ts-node
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcommon
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2frouter
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcompiler
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fforms
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcore
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fmaterial
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fjasmine
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-core
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/codelyzer
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jasmine-spec-reporter
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fjasminewd2
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-chrome-launcher
> 407 authenticationrequired - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma

I have also Set up my .npmrc like down below:

> proxy=http://xxxxxx%5CXUSRX:XXPASSXXX@someweb:someport 
> strict-ssl=false

What am I doing wrong here? I'm clueless at the moment. I also tried it with https config and adding registry to it. Nothing worked.

### Edit

I found out that npm install for example works! But if i try to use ng update it tells me "407 authentication required" I just have the issue when I use ng update, after a few minutes it shows me an error that the 407 authenticationrequired.

My npmrc is set correct and should be alright. Anyway it doesn't let do the get request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [407 Authentication required npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49902035/407-authentication-required-npm)

Comment: @PhilippMeissner it doesnt provide anything new i havent done.