# npm 407 Proxy Authentication Required - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/{package}

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I've tried [all these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49902035/407-authentication-required-npm), but none of them work.

I have the proxy configured in the `.gitconfig` file too, but this is working, and in npm, when I'm trying to install or publish a package, I get the error;

> `407 Proxy Authentication Required - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha`

or

> `407 Proxy Authentication Required - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/my-packaje`

**.npmrc file**:

```
proxy=http://user:password@proxy:8080/
```

Comment: Did you try to add `https-proxy=http://user:password@proxy:8080/`  to `.npmrc` also?

Comment: Also after editing please close the current terminal session and open a new one, because the new settings might not be available in an already running terminal session.

Comment: @MilanTenk I´ve tried both, but does not work for me

Comment: An alternative could be using a tool, that takes care of the proxy authentication. For example fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without username and password it works:

```
proxy=http://proxy:8080/
```