# TFS Git command line with special characters

Tags: git, tfs, special-characters

I want to launch a git clone command with my password and username but my password contains special characters (e.g.: `pass/word@123` ) :

```
git clone https://username:pass/word@123@mysite.com/myrepo
```

The command is obviously not working because it does wrongly interpret the special characters. I tried using [percent encoding](https://fabianlee.org/2016/09/07/git-calling-git-clone-using-password-with-special-character/) and backslash but it is still not working. Git says the authentication failed when I use `password%40123` instead of `password@123`. What can I do ?

Note : I am not using github, but Microsoft TFS.

Note 2 : I can not type the url first and the password after when git asks (because I try to run the command from PHP/Symfony (but percent encoding is still not working when using it directly from command line))

Note 3 : Of course I cannot change the password

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

After testing, it is working on a GitHub repo (with percent encoding) but not on TFS. So the problem is coming from TFS.

Comment: I have never had this problem. Are you on windows?

Comment: No. Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Is it possible for you to setup an SSH key then? This is strange though, I've been on Ubuntu since 14.04 and never encountered this ever.

Comment: No, the server is not accepting SSH key unfortunately.

Comment: tried double quotes (`"`) around the URL?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Version 15.117.27024.0 (TFS 2017)

Comment: @Damien so you should be able to connect with SSH keys.

Comment: Yes in theory it should, but it is not working on my repositories.

Comment: Did you follow this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=vsts

Comment: Yes, every step of it. SSH keys are definitively not working for me.

Comment: What's the detail error when you use tfs url  running git command? As a workaround, have you tried to use Git Credential Managers to Authenticate to VSTS (also work on Linux)?

Comment: If I let the @, it does not understand and try to use `123@mysite.com/myrepo ` as the url. `Cannot resolve host 123@mysite.com/myrepo`. If I use percent encoding, it says `Authentication failed`. I didn't tried Git Credential Managers but I tried to use PAT directly and it wasn't working (it prompted me for username and password whereas I put PAT in the url.). Don't they work the same way ?

Answer (score 3):

Just as you have said, it will treat characters after `@` as the remote site url.

Take a look at this thread: [How to provide username and password when run "git clone git@remote.git"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git)

It is more popular to use an **ssh key** instead of a password when automating a git clone from a guest OS.

If you want to use password with special character, like an exclamation mark, you need to use percent encoding which is often called URL encoding.

```
!   #   $    &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   /   :   ;   =   ?   @   [   ]
%21 %23 %24 %26 %27 %28 %29 %2A %2B %2C %2F %3A %3B %3D %3F %40 %5B %5D
```

More details please refer similar question here: [Escape @ character in git proxy password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password)

Comment: As I said before, ssh keys are not working because of our repository policies (and this cannot be changed). And it is not working to use percent-encoding to clone a TFS repository (authentication failed).

Comment: @Damien If so, I'm afraid you may have to change the password format, which should do the trick.

Comment: No, unfortunately, I am still stuck.