# Git push using credentials with login as email

Tags: git, credentials, git-push

Recently I have the following command to push to my git repository

```
git push https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@github.com/my-org/my-repo.git
```

But, now I should push when my GIT_USERNAME in the format of email like a: **test@test.com** and after that I have the following problem:

> Could not resolve host: test.com

How can I push to git using the username as email and password?

P.S. I cannot get any SSH keys. I have only username and password.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to encode the username before you push to ensure that the `@` is actually `%40` instead so it would actually look like `git push https://user%40test.com:password@github.com/my-org/my-repo.git` this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password

Comment: @Popeye thanks a lot. It helps!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape @ character in git proxy password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to encode the username before you push to ensure that the `@` is actually `%40` instead so it would actually look like `git push https://user%40test.com:password@github.com/my-org/my-repo.git`.

This [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) will explain more about URL Encoding if you want to read about it.