# How can pass password with '@' to GIT on the command line?

Tags: git, passwords

I know and use this in command line https://username:password@example.com.
But, what can i do when my password has a @? Something like passw@rd.

I forgot how do that, many unsuccessful attempts.

Comment: Have a look at
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape @ character in git proxy password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password)

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to try using the URL Encoded value of the @ symbol (%40).
If you're passing the password in the proxy .
e.g.:

```
http.proxy=http://userId:pwd%40123@ipaddress:port
```

Hope this helps you out.