# Configure git proxy

Tags: git, proxy, git-bash, configure

How to configure this:
http://USER:PASS@HOST:PORT 
my password contains @

is there an escape character?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape @ character in git proxy password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172719/escape-character-in-git-proxy-password)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+escape+%40

Answer (score -1):

Did you try a `\` before `@` in yours password?