# Docker for Mac and corporate proxy

Tags: docker, proxy, macos-catalina, docker-for-mac

I spent the whole day trying to pull an image on my MacBook through a corporate HTTP proxy, with no luck.
It is an authenticated proxy, of the form: `http://username:password-with-special-characters@proxy.domain:8080`
The `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables are set in my `.zshrc`.
The proxy details are set in the system's preferences.

When I try to `docker pull hello-world` without altering proxy settings in the Docker for Mac UI, I got:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Service Unavailable
```

When I also set the proxy through the Docker for Mac UI I got:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Proxy Authentication Required
```

I can curl https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ directly on the terminal, and get back a 200.

I tried with and without URI encoding the special characters in my password, doesn't change a thing.
I used to have some issues with the same proxy on a Linux machine, but got it to work by messing with `systemd`. On macOs, I don't know if I can do something similar.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: May be this help you -https://stackoverflow.com/a/54546625/410439

Answer (score 0):

For those who had this error, it was because of a bug between Cisco AnyConnect and Docker. This bug has been fixed with Docker for Mac 3.4.0.