# How do you use password as environment variable in git pull when it has special characters?

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUpbh.png

Hi I'm able to use the following command when i have plain password.

```
git pull http://$username:$password@github.com/pulkit889/project1.git
```

but it fails when password contains special character.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable

Comment: It's a URL, you'll possibly need to URL-encode it.

Comment: What are the problematic characters? Colon? Slash? At-sign? Whitespace? Accented characters?

Comment: basically all. Git has a thing where it ask to convert all special characters in '%hex' format.

Answer (score 0):

Got The answer.
You have to convert whole password in a string of hexadecimal characters separated by '%' sign. Used the following instead of just $password.

```
$(echo -n $password | hexdump -v -e '"x" 1/1 "%02X"' | tr x %)
```

found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53519379/11558375